# Pickle custom collections.abc.Mapping as dict

Tags: python, pickle

I have a custom facade that implements the collections.abc.Mapping mixin interface.

```
from collections import abc
from typing import Mapping

class MyMapping(abc.Mapping):
    def __init__(self, item:Mapping):
        self._item = item        
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._item[key]    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._item)    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._item)
```

I would like it if this class would be pickled as a dict. That is, I want the following to be true:

```
import pickle

#I'd like this statement to be true
pickle.dumps(MyMapping({'a':1})) == pickle.dumps({'a':1})
```

That being said I'd rather not have to convert all my types to dicts just to pickle them.

I've tried using `__reduce__` with a dict type in the first of the returned tuple but that doesn't work. Is there some other trick? Also, creating my own callable object to handle this or registering a dispatch reduction function also seems way overkill.

Comment: This seems really weird. Why do you want your instances to have this strange pickling behavior? If you actually depend on your instances behaving differently from dicts in some way, then pickling and unpickling will break the behavior you depend on. If you *don't* depend on your instances behaving differently from dicts in any way, then why not just use dicts?

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah it is weird, :). I'm working with datasets that have 100's of millions of these objects so using a builtin-type to pickle can really reduce the size of my pickle files (2x in my testing) and make a huge difference in pickling time (5x by my testing). I stripped out the extra functionality that the facade provides to make the question simpler, but the facade only really adds convenience methods. We can easily rewrap the facade on the otherside if we need to.

Comment: Okay, so what you *really* want is faster pickling and smaller pickles. If you got an answer that pickled your objects as dicts, but it took 10 times as long as pickling an actual dict, you would be unhappy. In that case, you should ask a question about optimized serialization, not a question about pickling your objects like dicts.

Comment: @user2357112 Unfortunately given what you suggest I'm afraid I will get answers I don't want. I have strict dependency constraints so I can only use internal Python modules. I can't use any serialization modules outside of the standard library. With that in mind I'm just assuming Python's built-in types are the fastest types for pickling in Python.

Comment: You're probably screwed for speed - what `pickle` is already doing is probably faster than anything you could write. You can probably save a bunch of space by changing your serialization format, but implicitly pickling your objects as dicts is both error-prone and probably not a great way to save space. If you want to save space, I'd actually suggest compression. Python comes with several modules for reading and writing common compression formats, like [`bz2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html) for the bz2 format and [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) for ZIP.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree, that's why I'm using pickle and wanted to make pickle as fast as possible by using the built-in types. What do you mean by pickling objects as dicts is error prone? I haven't read of Python having any problems with pickling and unpickling simple built-in types. I know some of the older protocol versions aren't supported by ancient versions of Python. Is there something I don't know? Also, thanks for the suggestion but I'm already compressing in addition to using pickle.

Comment: I mean that anything that relies on regular pickling behavior will break. For example, you'll have really weird bugs when you try to use your code with the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: Oh that's a really good point. I always forget about the GIL. Thanks for reminding me!